# 'fbxsdk.h' file not found in my Mac Qt project,How add FBX SDK in my Mac Qt project?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fbx

I developed a Qt project on Mac which transplanted from Windows Qt,everything is working fine in Windows Qt,but in Mac Qt show many errors, one of them is :
'fbxsdk.h' file not found
it seem to say I have not add FBX SDK to my Mac Qt project. so I add it according official website: https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_724E9FAD_AFA0_4348_BDAA_6CF2FDF2FF55_htm .

and study add FBX SDK in Windows Qt project in this website : https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/including-sdk-to-qt-creator/td-p/8184654 .

so I edit my .pro, the content is here :

```
LIBS += /Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ SDK/2019.2/lib/clang/debug/libfbxsdk.a
LIBS += /Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ SDK/2019.2/lib/clang/debug/libfbxsdk.dylib
INCLUDEPATH += /Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ SDK/2019.2/include
DEPENDPATH += /Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ SDK/2019.2/lib/clang
```

it still show error : 'fbxsdk.h' file not found, how should I add FBX\ SDK in my Mac Qt project,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed it:

I used the 'otool -L' with execute file of my App in the terminal,it shows the libfbxsdk.dylib load path is '@executable_path/libfbxsdk.dylib',in my '@executable_path/' there no libfbxsdk.dylib in it,so it shows error,so I think why the loadpath of 'libfbxsdk.dylib' is '@executable_path/libfbxsdk.dylib',can I change it?
the answer is 'YES'
how I change the 'install name' of libfbxsdk.dylib you can find in this pic :

[image]

of course,you can use a another popular way,change the loadpath of 'libfbxsdk.dylib' use the 'install_name_tool -change' in the terminal,here is my example to change it in pic:

[image]

now you use the 'otool -L' with execute file in the terminal again,the loadpath of libfbxsdk.dylib change to '/Applications/Autodesk/FBXSDK/2019.2/lib/clang/debug/libfbxsdk.dylib' from '@executable_path/libfbxsdk.dylib'